# Combining several collections into one

Tags: java, collections, guava

Is there a way to rewrite this code to make it more laconic? I'm using Java 6.

```
Object value = methodOutOfMyControl();        
Collection<LinkedHashSet<String>> values = ((Map) value).values();
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<String>();
for (LinkedHashSet<String> set : values) {
    strings.addAll(set);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that sometimes inlining some values makes things a little more readable. But in terms of overall compactness, this isn't that much better. Here is what I would probably write

```
Map value = (Map)methodOutOfMyControl();
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<String>();
for (Map.Entry<Object, LinkedHashSet<String>> set : value.entrySet()) {
    strings.addAll(set.getValue());
}
```

Comment: If possible, supply the instantiation of the set with an educated guess of the number of elements to support. `Map.entrySet()` may be costly, and I don't see it used to advantage (avoid lookups) here.

Answer (score 1):

While the cast to *Map anything to Collection* enables the use of a *foreach loop*, it wouldn't exactly express my intention (values better map to *Collections containing Strings, only*)

```
    int MEMBERS_TO_EXPECT = 12345;
    Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>(MEMBERS_TO_EXPECT);
    for (Collection more : ((Map<?, Collection>) value).values())
        strings.addAll(more);
// if modifications to strings shall be caught
    strings = Collections.unmodifiableSet(strings);
```